# How can I generate the waveform below and inject it into the LTspice circuit?

Tags: circuit-design, ltspice

[image]

Is there have any special function I can use in LTspice to generate this waveform voltage instead of just do an operating point analysis for different input voltages?

Answer (score 4):

Yes.

Take a look at the advanced options of the voltage source and select PWL, then enter your desired steps.

[image]

However, given how slow your voltage changes, you might as well do a `.dc` analysis and then just get the behavior of your circuit over the entire DC voltage range for you to view.

Comment: The `step` command will be helpful, unless OP is interested in the dynamic behaviour (in which case PWL is the deal).

Comment: @aconcernedcitizen I found a stepped `.op` to often come out much slower (even with few steps) than a `.dc` operation, so I suggested the latter. But of course you are right in that the combination of `.step` and `.op` does *exactly* what the questions seems to ask for.

Comment: I won't deny your experience, but I meant OP = original poster, that's why I used ` for `.step` (I missed the dot) but not for OP. It does look ambiguous. ;-)